# AttributeError: module 'missingno' has no attribute 'heatmap'

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I'm trying to output msno.heatmap on visual studio code and somehow it keeps give error saying 'seaborn' does not have attribute 'heatmap' even though I'm using mono.heatmap(). Can I please get some help to solve this? By the way, my missingno version is 0.4.2 and seaborn is 0.10.1

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotnine import *

import seaborn as sns
import missingno as msno

fifa_filepath = '/Users/sophie/Desktop/JanFlightDelay/Jan_2020_ontime.csv'
fifa_data = pd.read_csv(fifa_filepath)
msno.heatmap(fifa_data)
```

and my output gives

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/sophie/Desktop/Python practice/seaborn.py", line 7, in
> <module>
>     import seaborn as sns   File "/Users/sophie/Desktop/Python practice/seaborn.py", line 27, in <module>
>     msno.heatmap(fifa_data)   File "/Users/sophie/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/missingno/missingno.py",
> line 334, in heatmap
>     sns.heatmap(corr_mat, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, ax=ax0, cbar=cbar, AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'heatmap'
```

Comment: The name of your python file is also `seaborn.py` which maybe shadowing the `seaborn` package. Try renaming your python file

Comment: Cheers. I think that has solved my problem but heatmap does not appear anywhere on my visual studio. Is this normal or do I must put plt.show() at the end?